# Curator not finding my index

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-curator

Trying to have curator clean up an index I have named "syslog"

I have this action yml:

```
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Delete indices older than hour
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      timeout_override:
      continue_if_exception: False
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: syslog
      exclude:
    - filtertype: age
      source: name
      direction: older
      timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
      unit: hours
      unit_count: 1
      exclude:
```

I tried both "hours" and "days" but I keeping getting this message from curator:

```
 Skipping action "delete_indices" due to empty list: <class 'curator.exceptions.NoIndices'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling Curator that you want it to identify indices that have a prefix value of `syslog`, and also have a Year.Month.Day timestring in the index name.  This would match, for example, if the index name were `syslog-2017.03.14`.  But if the name of the index is only `syslog`, this filter set will not match.

Perhaps you want to catch the index age relative to when the index was created.  In this case you'd set

```
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Delete indices older than hour
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      timeout_override:
      continue_if_exception: False
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: regex
      value: '^syslog$'
    - filtertype: age
      source: creation_date
      direction: older
      unit: hours
      unit_count: 1
```

This will match *only* an index named `syslog` whose `creation_date` is at least one hour older than execution time.

Comment: Is there an advantage of matching on name instead of creation_date? Is creation_date local to the server or is that property attached to the index? Like if the index was moved to another server would that property remane?

Comment: "Is there an advantage of matching on name instead of `creation_date`?" Not really, but if you are trying to ingest older data, name is a better way to guarantee that you have the right time frame. "Is `creation_date` local to the server?" No, it's epoch time, plus milliseconds, ergo it is always in UTC.

Comment: what i mean is, is the creation_date property attached to the event object or is that value calculated by the server.

Comment: An elasticsearch cluster keeps a fully propagated set of cluster metadata. All index information is stored there. When a new index is created, a time stamp is stored as creation_date. It is not calculated. API calls to the cluster access this metadata. Because the metadata is cluster-wide, it doesn't matter where an index or its shards reside, the creation_date is the same.